# how to make mysql RIGHT() query in adonisJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, adonis.js

im trying SQL query `SELECT MAX(RIGHT(fieldlist, 3)) as list FROM table_db WHERE fieldlist LIKE 'ABC%'` in adonisJS

code :

```
 const noFaktur = await database
                .from("table_db")
                .max(right("fieldlist as list", 3))
                .where("fieldlist", "LIKE", 'ABC%')
```

but the result its "right its not defined"
Can i get help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adonisjs query builder [Knexjs](https://knexjs.org) does not have a dedicated MySQL right function you can use the below as a workaround,

```
 const noFaktur = await database
            .from("table_db")
            .max({ list: database.raw('RIGHT(fieldlist, 3)') })
            .where("fieldlist", "LIKE", 'ABC%')
```